# Task runner possibilites in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, gulp

With Visual Studio 2015 it is possible to have a gulpfile.js with built task. You can also use grunt. I have found a list of further options [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/01/06/task-runners-in-visual-studio-2015/).

My question is whether there is a similar option where I could define a build task in C# without the need to create a separate executable that will be called in a pre or post build action? Is there some way I could write a script in C# for build task in a very similar way as I can use gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add powershell scripts to your projects and have those executed with the pre/post build events. That is logically the same thing. You can also add targets to your .xxproj files to make those part of your build toolchain.

See this for more detail -> [Post build event execute powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500320/post-build-event-execute-powershell)

And some info on using targets -> [Adding and running custom target by msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459285/adding-and-running-custom-target-by-msbuild)